# How do Rorge and Biter end up with the Brave Companions?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

I don't see how Rorge and Biter were recruited in Brave Companions company.

At first, they were with Yoren's crew, heading to the Wall. They were attacked by Amory Lorch and escaped from their cage with an axe Arya gave them.

Were they captured by Amory Lorch or did they hide from the attackers ? Amory Lorch looked decided too kill evreybody of Yoren's crew.

Later, we see them with the Brave Companions. I don't think Amory would have sell them or given them to Vargo Hoat because Amory and Vargo disliked each other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They joined Amory Lorch after Arya saved them from the fire however it is not clear how they joined the Manticore's men. We only see them from Arya's POV and Arya did not see them since the time she saved them from fire surrounding their cage till she saw them again in Harrenhal, wearing Lannister uniforms.

From Arya's POV in ACOK:

> Then she saw the three near the end of the column.
>
> Rorge had donned a black halfhelm with a broad iron nasal that made it
>   hard to see that he did not have a nose. Biter rode ponderously beside
>   him on a destrier that looked ready to collapse under his weight.
>   Halfhealed burns covered his body, making him even more hideous than
>   before.
>
> But Jaqen H’ghar still smiled. His garb was still ragged and filthy,
>   but he had found time to wash and brush his hair. It streamed down
>   across his shoulders, red and white and shiny, and Arya heard the
>   girls giggling to each other in admiration.
>
> I should have let the fire have them.

Later, Brave Companions brought some northern captives to Harrenhal. Arya forced Jaqen to help her free them. Jaqen brought them along.

*The Weasel Soup* incident is:

> The Brave companions switched sides and joined the Starks. That
>  resulted in occupation of Harrenhal by Roose Bolton and death of Amory
>  Lorch, Lannister appointed commander of Harrenhal. Arya, Jaqen, Rorge and biter helped by freeing the Northmen, unaware that this was the plan of Brave companions all along.

So They helped Jaqen and Arya in the Weasel Soup incident:

> Then she heard the ugly sound of Rorge’s voice. “Cook,” he shouted.
>   “We’ll take your bloody broth.” Arya let go of the spoon in dismay. I
>   never told him to bring them. Rorge wore his iron helmet, with the
>   nasal that half hid his missing nose. Jaqen and Biter followed him
>   into the kitchen.
>
> “The bloody broth isn’t bloody ready yet,” the cook said. “It needs to
>   simmer. We only now put in the onions and-”
>
> “Shut your hole, or I’ll shove a spit up your ass and we’ll baste you
>   for a turn or two. I said broth and I said now.”

Later, They apparently joined the Brave companions after the *Weasel Soup incident*. They told so to Ser Robbet Glover after the incident:

> "This of the soup, that was clever,” the man Glover was saying. “I did
>   not expect that. Was it Lord Hoat’s idea?”
>
> Rorge began to laugh. He laughed so hard that snot flew out the hole
>   where his nose had been. Biter sat on top of one of the dead men,
>   holding a limp hand as he gnawed at the fingers. Bones cracked between
>   his teeth.
>
> “Who are you men?” A crease appeared between Robett Glover’s brows.
>   “You were not with Hoat when he came to Lord Bolton’s encampment.
>   **Are you of the Brave Companions?**”
>
> **Rorge wiped the snot off his chin with the back of his hand. “We are now.”**
>
> “This man has the honor to be Jaqen H’ghar, once of the Free City of
>   Lorath. This man’s discourteous companions are named Rorge and Biter.
>   A lord will know which is Biter.” He waved a hand toward Arya. “And
>   here-”
>
> “I’m Weasel,” she blurted, before he could tell who she really was.

Then Jaqen left for good and the two criminals appear to have been associated with the Qohorik mercenaries known as the Brave companions from that point onwards:

> Until the eventual re-capture of Harrenhal by Gregor Clegane and
>  desertion of the Brave companions in different bands, trying to find a
>  passage across the narrow sea. The two criminals took to terrorizing
>  the peasants in Riverlands.

Comment: OK, that makes sense... I did not remember that precise part. 
But still, I wonder how they manage to join Amory's men...

Comment: @Bebs That part hasn't been explained in the books which is why I said _it is not clear how they did that_. If I were to speculate, I'd say that they would have used the fact that they were caged by the NW and looked like warriors to persuade Amory Lorch to take them on.